# Find the volume of a region using the shell method: $x^\frac{2}{3}+y^\frac{2}{3}=4$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

A region $R$ is bounded above by the graph of $x^\frac{2}{3}+y^\frac{2}{3}=4$ and below by the x-axis. Find the volume of the region. Rotating region $R$ about the vertical line $x=8$ generates a solid of revolution $S$. I am confused with the picture below. Why is the radius considered to be $8-x$ shouldn't it be $x-8$?

[image: shell-method]

Comment: For the shell drawn in the diagram above, $x$ appears to be approximately $2$.  So the radius is $8-x = 8-2 = 6$.  By your reasoning, the radius would be $x-8 = 2-8 = -6$.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius ought to be shown as $|x-8|$ or $|8-x|$ as a radius is a length quantity which *cannot* be negative, thus this would account for if $x<8$ or $x>8$ and give a positive value in either case.